# How do you measure the difference between two sounds using the Web Audio API?

Tags: javascript, audio, web-audio-api

I'm attempting to measure the difference between two sounds using an analyser node and getByteFrequencyData(). I thought that by summing the difference in each frequency bin I could come up with a single number to represent how different the two sounds were. Then I would be able to change the sounds and measure the numbers again to see if the new sound was more or less different than before.

Does getByteFrequencyData() fully encompass the representation of a sound or do I need to include other pieces of data to qualify the sound?

Here is the code I'm using:

```
var Spectrogram = (function(){
    function Spectrogram(ctx) {
        this.analyser = ctx.createAnalyser();
        this.analyser.fftSize = 2048;
        this.sampleRate = 512;

        this.scriptNode = ctx.createScriptProcessor(this.sampleRate, 1, 1);
        this.scriptNode.onaudioprocess = this.process.bind(this);

        this.analyser.connect(this.scriptNode);

        this.startNode = this.analyser;
        this.endNode = this.scriptNode;

        this.data = [];
    }

    Spectrogram.prototype.process = function(e) {
        var d = new Uint8Array(this.analyser.frequencyBinCount);
        this.analyser.getByteFrequencyData(d);
        this.data.push(d);

        var inputBuffer = e.inputBuffer;
        var outputBuffer = e.outputBuffer;
        for(var channel = 0; channel < outputBuffer.numberOfChannels; channel++) {
            var inputData = inputBuffer.getChannelData(channel);
            var outputData = outputBuffer.getChannelData(channel);
            for(var sample = 0; sample < inputBuffer.length; sample++) {
                outputData[sample] = inputData[sample];
            }
        }
    };

    Spectrogram.prototype.compare = function(other) {
        var fitness = 0;
        for(var i=0; i<this.data.length; i++) {
            if(other.data[i]) {
                for(var k=0; k<this.data[i].length; k++) {
                    fitness += Math.abs(this.data[i][k] - other.data[i][k]);
                }
            }
        }
        return fitness;
    }

    return Spectrogram;
})();
```

Comment: You need to consider what it means to you for sounds to be different.  Certainly `getByteFrequencyData` represents the sound in some way, but I don't know if it captures what you want.  Consider if you have a sound.  Now reduce the amplitude by a factor of 2.  Are the sounds the same?  Should they be considered to be the same sounds?  You need to define what it means to be the "same" before you can come up with an algorithm to tell you.

Comment: I guess for sounds to be the same they would sound the same to a human ear. So amplitude would be a part of the equation. On analyser nodes there is also getByteTimeDomainData() which description is "the current time-domain or waveform" would that encompass the amplitude?

Comment: Yes, it would include amplitude information.  But you probably want to use `getFloatTimeDomainData` instead of `getByteTimeDomainData`.

Comment: I guess that similarly to image processing, there's gonna be several methods and several tricks - time offset, volume offset, pitch offset - all these things may be needed to be filtered out to get some real results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the spectralFlux function provided by the Meyda package to compare two signals. Spectral flux is, according to wikipedia, "usually calculated as the 2-norm (also known as the Euclidean distance) between the two normalised spectra."

After runninng `npm install --save meyda`, you would do something like:

```
const spectralFlux = require('meyda/src/extractors/spectralFlux');

const difference = spectralFlux({
  signal: [your first signal],
  previousSignal: [your second signal]
});
```

Feel free to just copy the code from [here](https://github.com/hughrawlinson/meyda/blob/master/src/extractors/spectralFlux.js) so that you don't have to handle the dependency, the codebase is appropriately licensed.

It will return a coefficient of how "different" the two signals sound. You could do this in either the time domain, or the frequency domain. You'd get different numbers, but both would correlate with how "different" the sounds are from each other.

But "difference" may not describe the differences accurately enough for your use case. For instance, you may care a lot about volume differences, and not very much about timbral differences, but the spectral flux metric doesn't take that into account. You may wish to run each signal through feature extractors first, find other statistics about their properties such as their perceptual volume, their brightness, etc, and then take a weighted euclidean distance between those data, which would provide a more tailored "difference" metric to what you need for your purpose.

Happy to elaborate further, but this is already pretty long for a SO answer.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to your project on github! Looks really useful. Are you planning on adding more sound comparison tooling?

Comment: @JustusRomijn I'm happy to add whatever would be useful :)